# Comment formatting, specifying * and indentation

Tags: vim, comments

For now my comments are formated like this:

```
/*
 * comments
 */
```

When I press `/* *return*` there is an extra space and `*`.

I have to respect a convention, so I need that my comments looks like this :

```
/*
** comments
*/
```

Does someone know how to configure this in vim?
(During a comment, when I press return, insert "** " instead of " * ")

Comment: You can try to `set comments=sr:/*,m:**,ex:*/`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `'comments'`  option.  Please check `:h format-comments` to read
more  about this,  and configure  your  options accordingly.  Here is  a
suggestion of flags to use:

```
s:/*,m:**,ex:*/
```

This  allows easy  closing  of the  comment (`x`  flag)  and the  middle
behavior  that you  described. You  didn't mention  the language  you're
using, but let's assume it is C  and Objective-C in which you need this.
I like  to keep  my configuration  stuff in my  *.vimrc*; so  instead of
creating or modifying the language files, I'd add this auto-command:

```
 autocmd FileType c,objc setlocal comments=s:/*,m:**,ex:*/
```

Comment: In this case, `setlocal` could be preferable.

Comment: @ryuichiro Certainly, thanks, edited. Sorry if I seem to repeat your comment, but I was already writing when you left the comment in the question :-o